# Convert hash to NSNumberWithInt inconsistent?

Tags: objective-c, hash, key-value

I am storing an object's hash value as a unique identifier within that object like so:

```
[myObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[myObj hash]] forKey:@"ID"];
```

But when retrieving the value for that key, the value is no longer consistent with the hash, to wit this code:

```
NSLog(@"[myObj hash] %i",[myObj hash]);
NSLog(@"[myObj hash] NSNumber %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:[myObj hash]]);
[myObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[myObj hash]] forKey:@"ID"];
NSLog(@"myObj ID %@",[myObj valueForKey:@"ID"]);
```

Produces output similar to:

```
[myObj hash] -976941568
[myObj hash] NSNumber -976941568
myObj ID 3584
```

What basic things about hash and/or key/value pairs do I clearly not understand?

Thompson

[EDIT]

Pardon my newbie manners!  myObj is a NSManagedObject, and is key/value compliant, so ID is simply a key I create on the fly.

Comment: Whenever you unexpectedly encounter a high-magnitude negative number, you should immediately check whether you are displaying an unsigned value as if it was signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash method returns an unsigned integer, try this instead

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[myObj hash]];
```